# Is it possible to change the root password with normal user credential?

Tags: terminal, root

I have hacked my server and can't access with root permission. but I know old password for root and then also know a normal user info.
Can I recover my root password or add root permission to normal user info?
When you know about it, Please some help.

Comment: Login as yourself. Does `sudo -s` with _your own password_ give you a root shell?

Comment: As roaima already pointed out - The answer is: Only if that normal user has appropriate sudo priviledges (you already said that you *don't know* the current root password)...

Comment: Do you have physical access to "your server"? As in: can you take out the harddisk, and hook it up to a different computer? Or boot from an USB stick? Both ways can be used to reset the root password.

Comment: If OP has physical access to the machine, booting into a root shell is quicker and easier.

Comment: `su - passwd root`

Comment: @Artem S. Tashkinov first can you tell me about this? su - passwd root

Comment: @roaima , No, It can access root shell

Comment: @dirkt sorry, It's vps server

Comment: If it's a VPS server, then (1) you should have a backup of all important data somewhere else, (2) you should be able to re-deploy your server by wiping out the old one and installing a new image. If you can't do either, now you know why you need it. In addition, read up on ssh keys. Also, sometimes VPS providers have a method to get root, so read your VPS provider's documentation if you don't what to tell us which VPS provider and what kind of VPS it is.

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the steps in:
https://linuxconfig.org/recover-reset-forgotten-linux-root-password

Short:

1. Boot into recovery mode
2. Mount the root partition in rw mode
3. use passwd to set a new password
4. reboot

I had to do this once, it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If your user account has `sudo` rights you can login as your usual user account and elevate your privileges to those of root

```
sudo -s
```

Once you've here you can run whatever commands you need to regain direct access to your tour account. For example to change its password,

```
passwd root
```

Comment: So the answer to the actual question seems therefore to be "no, it is not possible to change the password for root with non-root credentials" (as you are actually root when issuing the `passwd` command).